# Pass NSString from an UIViewController to another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, uistoryboardsegue, swift2

I am trying to pass a string value from a ViewController to another:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMasterViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        let viewController:MyViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! MyViewController

        sprite = viewController.sp //sp is NSString declared in MyViewController
        print("the string is \(viewController.sp)")// nothing happens!!!


    }
```

I can see that `sp` IS NOT `nil` in my log before "leaving" `MyViewController`.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I think I may know the issue:

In log the `@IBAction func unwindToMasterViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)` is called before I get the string value from `MyViewController`.

The order the log appears is:

1. `"the string is "`

and then the print from `MyViewController` with the actual value:

2. `"sp is testString"`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does it ever execute the print statement?

Comment: @der_michael yes it does execute the print but i only see in the log "the string is" but nothing else not even 'null' or 'nil'

Comment: Then maybe clarify what your problem is in particular or do you want just a recommendation in general? Because there are multiple ways to pass data between view controllers. Your option shown is a valid one of them and they all greatly depend on what yo are trying to achieve... What is it in particular that you do not like about your solution?

Comment: Are you sure that it's segueing from the correct MyViewController?

Comment: @der_michaelmy problem is that I get nothing. I cannot pass the string from one view to the other. sp is always nil. So basically I am wondering where i go wrong...

Comment: I think I may know the issue: In log the @IBAction func unwindToMasterViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) is called before I get the string value from the MyViewController. The order the log appears is: "the string is " and then the print from the MyViewController with the actual value. How do I solve this?

Comment: so you are using segue right ?

Comment: @Lamar yes that is correct (use the unwindSegue --->Exit)

Comment: so lets say you a VC1 and VC2 and the UIbutton is at VC1 when you pressed you want data to be passed from VC1 to VC2 right

Comment: @Lamar From VC1 i go to VC2 add the value to my string in VC2 then I tap on a tableviewcell and go back to VC1.

Comment: so if you have cell, i believe you have an array of data populating those cells right? if yes  VC2 is the source you should set up the object for that like **var object = arrayofData[indexPath.row]** then you use that **object** to send the data back to VC1... I believe ... this is a theory i never tried it like that

Comment: @Lamar sort of. but yes that is the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87838/discussion-between-george-asda-and-lamar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here's the solution in case anyone else come across this.

The problem was (as suspected) that the segue was called BEFORE I could pass the value to the NSString. That was because I was using the unwind segue connected straight from IB to the MasterView.

I had to delete the unwind segue and do it programmatically when my UITbleViewCell was tapped (didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Then the right sequence of events unfold:
Get the value from cell and then execute the segue. 
That way the value was passed to the MasterViewController as expected.

It goes beyond me why this happened or what is the reason to call the unwind segue before the action is called, but Apple works in mysterious ways...

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked for me

```
 @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let VC = ViewController()
    let string = VC.sp
    println(string)
    delegate?.addTaskCanceled!("task canceled")

}
```

and in the main VC I had this at the top:

```
  let sp:NSString = "Test"
```